# How can I make pylint not complain about a global argparse.Namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

If I run these contents (flags.py) through pylint3:

```
import argparse

FLAGS = argparse.Namespace()
_PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser()
_PARSER.add_argument('--edit', action='store_true')
_PARSER.parse_args(sys.argv, namespace=FLAGS)

def test():
  print(FLAGS.edit)
```

Among other errors (which I know how to fix), I get this error:

```
E: 12,8:test: Instance of 'Namespace' has no 'edit' member
```

I can fix this by not using the `namespace` argument to `parse_args`, but I use the `namespace` argument because it allows me to do

```
from flags import FLAGS
FLAGS.edit
```

anywhere I want to access my flags instead of:

```
import flags
flags.FLAGS.edit
```

which is, IMO, a lot uglier.

I'd love to have some way to quell this error message specifically on this FLAGS object.  Is there any way to do that?

(I'd be open to some better way of doing flags too, although that's probably not on topic for this question.  Also, yes, I know this involves global state, which is Bad (TM).  I'm happy with it, since command-line arguments are global anyway, and this seems the cleanest way to do it to me.)

Comment: There's no difference between writing `from flags import FLAGS` and accessing `FLAGS` and writing `import flags` and accessing `flags.FLAGS`. Using the `namespace` keyword argument is independent of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `getattr(FLAGS, 'edit')`

dstromberg's argument about letting pylint know what's going on is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I have two things to say about this:

1. I do argument parsing manually, because I want pylint to be able to
   tell what's going on.  The various modules that make argument
   parsing are convenient, but not worth the price IMO
2. I sometimes use http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/this-pylint/trunk/
   to eliminate errors from pylint that just won't go away otherwise